# Need to change a config setting of a deployed .net app without rebuilding it

Tags: c#, sql

Long ago i created a WinForms app with VS 2005. The app is still deployed and working using web services, it accesses a SQL server database.
The database server is changing credentials now because of a move.
I need to somehow provide a new connectionString to the app without rebuilding it, i dont know which assemblies to change and how, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the connection string now?  In app.config? If so just change it there.

Comment: Not clear what kind of help you are looking from SO. We can't find out how you configure connection string...

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear enough, I dont have the ability to use VS to build again the app, i dont even think i can find the source code any more. Is the file app.config somewhere in the deployed area? Where can i find it?